# Не могу сделать предсказание по обученной модели

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Всем добрый день.

Обучил простейшую нейросеть, но не могу сделать на ней предсказание, вылезает следующая ошибка:

**ValueError: Error when checking input: expected sequential_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 32, 32, 3).**

А вылезает она на этой строчке:
`preds = model.predict(image)`

Как я понял, ошибка может быть в архитектуре сети, но как исправить - не понимаю. Только начал разбираться в нейронках.

Архитектура нейросети:

````
model.add(Dense(6142, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax"))
# инициализируем скорость обучения и общее число эпох
INIT_LR = 0.01
EPOCHS = 60```

model.summary() показывает это [1]:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkdWm.png
````

Comment: Откуда берётся 6142? Что показывает model.summary() ?

Comment: А что вы подаёте на вход, когда обучаете модель? Подозреваю, что там не просто image подаётся, а как-то преобразуется при этом. Точно такое же преобразование нужно сделать с image и прежде чем подавать его на predict.

Comment: В частности, у вас похоже RGB каналы подаются на вход, а модель этого судя по ошибке не ожидает, она ждёт 2-мерный массив на входе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было подавать на вход обученной модели двумерный массив, как сказал CrazyElf. Но помимо этого ошибка была в размерах изображений и количестве нейронов на входном слое.

То есть, если размер входного изображения 32*32 и оно содержит 3 цветовых фильтра (RGB), то количество нейронов входного слоя должно быть 32*32*3=3072.

При этом модель должно как обучаться с такими параметрами, так и прдсказывать с теми же параметрами!

Всем спасибо)